# Search for the original date - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, date, stored-procedures, find

I need to find the original date of a pedimento (CUSTOMS document)
I have 2 tables DS_551 (The details table) and DS_701 the rectified pedimentos table.

And the structure of the tables are similar to this

DS_551

- Patente
- Pedimento
- Aduana
- Fecha Pago
- Value

DS_701

- Patente
- Pedimento
- Aduana
- Fecha Pago
- PatenteAnterior
- PedimentoAnterior
- AduanaAnterior
- FechaAnterior

And i need to find the original date per example:

> Format: (Patente-Pedimento-Aduana)

- Original pedimento: 4020-8000001-400
- 1st rectification: 4020-8009005-400
- 2nd rectification: 4020-9001003-400

In all the cases i would have on my table (DS_551) only the last rectification in this case the 2nd (4020-9001003-400) but i need to update the row with the original pedimento date a.k.a fecha (4020-8000001-400)

on my table DS_701 the rows are similar to this

```
Patente|Pedimento|Aduana|Fecha Pago|PatenteAnterior|PedimentoAnterior|AduanaAnterior|FechaAnterior|
4020|9001003|400|2017-11-17|4020|8009005|400|2017-10-17|
4020|8009005|400|2017-10-17|4020|8000001|400|2016-01-01|
```

In the example above the 1st row references to the data of the 2nd rectification and the previus document (the 1st rectification) and the 2nd row references to the data of the 1st rectification and the original document in the tables the word at the end "Anterior" references to the previus document data, so only having the data 4020|9001003|400 i need to find the date (fecha) of the document 4020|8000001|400

```
SELECT * FROM DS_551 WHERE CONCAT(Patente, Pedimento, Aduana) IN (SELECT CONCAT(Patente, Pedimento, Aduana) FROM DS_701)
```

the above query returns the list of the documents that i need to find the original date or the documents that have an rectification.

given the above list of documents how i can loop over each item to find the original date of them?? each document can have infinite number of rectifications.

I'm doing this on a stored procedure on MYSQL

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f0a5/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:
Try this instead http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f0a5/45

```
SELECT a.original_pedimento, a.original_fecha, b.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT  patente,
            aduana,
            MIN(CAST(pedimentoanterior AS UNSIGNED)) AS original_pedimento,
            MIN(CAST(fechaanterior AS DATE)) AS original_fecha
    FROM ds_701
    GROUP BY patente , aduana
    ) a INNER JOIN ds_701 b
            ON  a.patente = b.patente
            AND a.aduana = b.aduana
```

Deleted / Ignore:

```
SELECT *
FROM DS_701
WHERE Patente = '4020' and Aduana = '400'
ORDER BY CAST(PedimentoAnterior as unsigned) ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: It can't be directly like that, since there is a lot of another documents history in the table (Around 200k+) i need the first revision of the actual document, we need to follow the history of each document of the list to get the date of the originals of each of these.

Comment: Updated the SQL. Assuming the smallest PedimentoAnterior is the original document this returns the following: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f0a5/45

Answer (score 0):

This is the question:

**how i can** ... **find the original date...??**

For '4020' as the search string, the "original date" from the given data is **2016-01-01**

This query, will return the "original date" for '4020'

```
  set @patente := '4020';
  select 
      min(lafecha)
  from (
        select  Patente, Pedimento, Aduana, `FechaPago` lafecha
        from  DS_701
        where Patente = @patente
        union
        select  PatenteAnterior, PedimentoAnterior, FechaAnterior, FechaAnterior
        from DS_701
        where PatenteAnterior = @patente
        ) d1
```

**The result is:**

```
| min(lafecha) |
|--------------|
|   2016-01-01 |
```

We can take it a step further:

```
set @patente := '4020';
select
*
from DS_701
where Patente = @patente
and coalesce(FechaAnterior,FechaPago) =
     (select 
          min(lafecha)
      from (
            select  Patente, Pedimento, Aduana, `FechaPago` lafecha
            from  DS_701
            where Patente = @patente
            union
            select  PatenteAnterior, PedimentoAnterior, FechaAnterior, FechaAnterior
            from DS_701
            where PatenteAnterior = @patente
            ) d1
     )
;
```

**Which returns the "original" row:**

```
| ID | Patente | Pedimento | Aduana |  FechaPago | PatenteAnterior | PedimentoAnterior | AduanaAnterior | FechaAnterior |
|----|---------|-----------|--------|------------|-----------------|-------------------|----------------|---------------|
|  2 |    4020 |   8009005 |    400 | 2017-10-17 |            4020 |           8000001 |            400 |    2016-01-01 |
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/64f0a5/52

Comment: Thanks but is not what I'm trying to do, each document has a Patente, Pedimento, Aduana, this 3 fields are the link data of a unique document, a change in any of the 3 fields means its a different document

Comment: I want the complete history, but first i need to get the previous document of the last one or the one in my table DS_501, after that i need to search the previous of the one i just got in the previous search and do that until there is no more previous documents in the history table a.k.a DS_701

Comment: following the example i want to update the document or row (4020|9001003|400) with the date of the document 4020|8000001|400|, but i can't get it just directly since i need to follow all the history of the documents, since its unknow for me the number of previous documents each of these has

Comment: So with 4020|9001003|400 i get the data of 4020|8009005|400 and with this one i get the date i need from 4020|8000001|400

Comment: just fyi 

Patente = customs agent number, Pedimento = document number, aduana = customs location

Comment: Instead of many small comments with data snipptes, please add table of reusable sample data into the question (or create a http://sqlfiddle.com and share the url)